# Determine $f(r)$ so that the field may be irrotational and solenoidal

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields, divergence-operator, curl

> A vector field $\mathbf{A}$ in space is defined by $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{R} f(r)$, where $\mathbf{R}=xi+yj+zk$ and $r=(x^2+y^2+z^2 )^{1/2}$.
> Determine $f(r)$ so that the field may be irrotational and solenoidal.

I know for vector field $\mathbf{A}$ to be irrotational the curl of $\mathbf{A}$ should be zero and similarly for vector field $\mathbf{A}$ to be solenoidal the divergence of $\mathbf{A}$ should be zero.

But I am stuck because I do not able to comprehend how to incorporate $f(r)$ which is required. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $f$ is differentiable, since $\mathbf{A}=(xf(r),yf(r),zf(r))$ then, by the chain rule, it follows  that
$$\begin{align}\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}&=\frac{\partial (xf(r))}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial (yf(r))}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial (zf(r))}{\partial z}\\
&=3f(r)+f'(r)\left(x\frac{x}{r}+y\frac{y}{r}+z\frac{z}{r}\right)=3f(r)+f'(r)r.
\end{align}$$
Notice that $\mathbf{A}$ is a central vector field and therefore it is easy to check that $\nabla \times \mathbf{A}=\mathbf{0}$.

Therefore it remains to solve the ODE:
$$3f(r)+f'(r)r=0.$$
By [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) we get
$$\frac{f'(r)}{f(r)}=-\frac{3}{r}\Leftrightarrow \ln(f(r))=-3\ln(r)+c \Leftrightarrow f(r)=\frac{C}{r^3}.$$

Comment: I have computed the curl of vector field A by the concept which you have explained. The terms of f'(r) in i, j and k get cancelled. The end result is mixture of partial derivatives with f(r) as common. As it is given that field is solenoidal and irrotational, if I use the relation from divergence in curl. f(r) just replaced by f'(r) and I am unable to solve it futhermore.

Comment: You just have to solve a simple ODE in one variable: $3f(r)+f'(r)r=0$.

Comment: Thanks @RobertZ I have done it as you said and answer is f(r) = e^(3/r^2)
If it is the answer then we don't have to use the condition of irrotationality. Is it some extra information. Am I right?

Comment: No, it is not. Check your computations.

Comment: As 3f(r)+f′(r)r=0                

-3f(r)=f′(r)r          

f'(r)=-3/r f(r)       

f'(r)/f(r) = -3/r       

ln[f(r)] = -3 (-r^-2)      

ln[f(r)] = 3 r^-2      

ln[f(r)] = 3/r^2     

So, f(r) = exp (3/r^2)     

Is this wrong?

Comment: @HammadTahir See my edit.

Comment: Thank you so so much.